# Fastest way to send keystrokes C#

Tags: c#, .net, performance, testing

I was wondering what the fastest way to send keystrokes using C# is. Currently I am using `SendKeys.Send()` and `SendKeys.SendWait()` with `SendKeys.Flush()`.

I am using the following code to calculate the time of how long it takes for the both of them to work:

```
Stopwatch sw1 = new Stopwatch();
sw1.Start();
for (int a = 1; a <= 1000; a++)
{
    SendKeys.Send("a");
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
}
sw1.Stop();
```

And:

```
Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();
sw2.Start();
for (int b = 1; b <= 1000; b++)
{
    SendKeys.SendWait("b");
    SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
    SendKeys.Flush();
}
sw2.Stop();
```

The results of the 2 are:

```
Result 1: 40119 milliseconds
Result 2: 41882 milliseconds
```

Now if we put the `SendKeys.Flush()` on the second test, outside of the loop we get:

```
Result 3: 46278 milliseconds
```

I was wondering why these changes in the code make the speed very different.

I was also wondering if there is a faster way of sending many keystrokes, as my application does it a lot. (These tests were done on a really slow netbook)

Thanks!

Comment: Why does this need to be *"fast"*?

Comment: It already is fast, but I was wondering what the fastest way was because I thought there was different ways to do it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`SendWait()` is slower because it *waits* that the message has been processed by the target application. The `Send()` function instead doesn't wait and returns as soon as possible. If the application is somehow busy the difference can be even much more evident.

If you call `Flush()` you'll stop your application to process **all** events related to the keyboard that are queued in the message queue. It doesn't make too much sense if you sent them using `SendWait()` and you'll slow down a lot the application because it's inside the loop (imagine `Flush()` as a selective `DoEvents()` - yes with all its drawbacks - and it's called by `SendWait()` itself too).

If you're interested about its performance (but they'll always be limited to the speed at which your application can process the messages) please read [this on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx). In sum, you can change the `SendKeys` class to use the `SendInput` function, rather than a journal hook. As quick reference, simply add this setting to your app.config file:

```xml
<appSettings>
    <add key="SendKeys" value="SendInput"/>
</appSettings>
```

Anyway, the goal of the new implementation isn't the speed but consistent behavior across different versions of Windows and and options (the increased performance is kind of a side effect, I guess).

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to believe that calling `SendInput` is faster than using a journal hook (or vice versa)?

Comment: @CodyGray Primary 'cause MSDN: "The new implementation...is slightly faster..." anyway I imagine because it uses a more simple mechanism to send inputs (just SendInput instead of a hook).

Answer (score 11):

If you have a lot of text to push to a client, you may notice that SendKeys is really sluggish. You can vastly speed things up by using the clipboard. The idea is to put the text you wish to "type" into a target text box in the clipboard and then send a CTRL-V to the target application to paste that text. Here's an illustration:

```
Clipboard.Clear();  // Always clear the clipboard first
Clipboard.SetText(TextToSend);
SendKeys.SendWait("^v");  // Paste
```

I found this worked well for me with a cordless bar code scanner that talks via WiFi to a host app that sends long bar codes to a web app running in Google Chrome. It went from tediously pecking out 30 digits over about 4 seconds to instantly pasting all in under a second.

One obvious downside is that this can mess with your user's use of the clipboard. Another is that it doesn't help if you intend to send control codes like TAB or F5 instead of just plain old text.

Comment: +1. If you want to insert text into a text box this answer is the best option, especially if the text contains SendKey's special characters such as `{`, or strange unicode characters and the stuff; in which case you should be careful sending the chars one by one.